# Searching for identical NSManagedObject in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am newbie in coredata and I want to know how tell if an object is identical and already exist lets say for example I save a News model(NSManagedObject) with a title and content and save it, later I have instantiated another News model with the same title and content is there a way to tell that this object already exist? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find *another News model with the same title and content*, you need to first query using a compare on both content and title before instantiating another News model.

Here's what your NSPredicate might look like:

```
NSString *newContent = @"SomeNewContentValue";
NSString *newTitle = @"SomeNewTitleValue";

NSPredicate *newsFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title==[cd]%@ AND content==[cd]%@", newTitle, newContent];
```

Observe the *[cd]* string options which make your comparison both case and diacritic insensitive.  This, of course, assumes you need it to be case-insensitive.  Otherwise, leave out the *[cd]* in either spot.

Comment: Case sensitivity surely depends on the OP's implementation/idea of equality.

Comment: Also consider that `content = "abcdef"` may not be the same entity as `content = "ABCDEF"`, that's what I meant by case sensitivity

Comment: Thanks @Paul.s.  Answer has been modified.